# git allways throws error "unable to update url base from redirection"

Tags: git, bitbucket

My company is hosting a repo an bitbucket. I cloned that repo and it worked find. But now when I try to pull or push I always get this error

```
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
asked for: https://<my_username>@bitbucket.<company_name>.eu/scm/baprjrobe/ba_prj_timetracking.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
redirect: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<some_hash>/saml2?SAMLRequest=<a_super_long_hash>
```

when I follow the redirect link I land on `https://jira.<company_name>.eu/secure/Dashboard.jspa`
There I can enter my username and password and login.

From what I red I should set the git credential.helper and then pull again. However I just get the same error again. Basically git never asks for my credentials. Only when I initially cloned the repo (using the https address) a popup showed up where I had to enter my credentials. I thought that these credentials then would be saved to be used for pushing and pulling on that repo but apparently thats not the case.

So what do I have to do so I can push and pull using the terminal?

Comment: I would consult with your it or teammates about your configuration

Comment: Is SSH an option?